# AutoComplete Rails jquery validations

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

trying to get the input to validate that the entered value is in the data element on blur function and if not to clear the input and get focus.
I can see the element if i output the data but just cant get it to compare

help would be appreciated

```
$('#ticket_source_name').on('railsAutocomplete.select', function(event, data){
        console.log('autocomplete select fired')
        $(this).blur(function(event){
            $(this).val((data.item ? data.item.self : "")).focus()
            console.log($(this).data.item)
          });
      });
```

Comment: Eventually got this to work by changing to the `.change` instead of .`blur` method by would appreciate it if somebody could explain why this is.

Answer (score 0):

For your comment that `blur` only triggered when `focus lost` but `change triggered` when element state get changed

Comment: I had both triggering but as I could see the data in the console when testing. But I just can get my head around why `$(this).val((data.item ? data.item.self : "")).focus()` would would with one not the other ?